# R - Non-numeric argument to binary operator when dividing variable by participant-wise mean of that variable

Tags: r

I have a problem with some code.
My goal is to divide each value of the latency variable by the mean for latency of each individual participant.That means, I want to divide all latencies of participant 1 by the mean latency of participant, all latencies of participant 2 by the mean latency of participant 2 and so forth.
The error message is:

"Error in latency/mean(latency, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(latency) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(latency, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

Importantly, the code works with another dataset.
Below find the code I used to try and achieve this and some example data to reproduce the error:

````
              rt = df2$latency) as.numeric(df2$latency) na.omit(df2$latency) temp <-  ddply(xy, c('participant'), transform, avg = mean(latency),
          x = latency / mean(latency, na.rm = TRUE)

#Example Data
> dput(head (df2, 20))
structure(list(participant = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), timestamp = c(1547125307L, 
1547125307L, 1547125307L, 1547125307L, 1547125307L, 1547125307L, 
1547125307L, 1547125307L, 1547125307L, 1547125307L, 1547125307L, 
1547125307L, 1547125307L, 1547125307L, 1547125307L, 1547125307L, 
1547125307L, 1547125307L, 1547125307L, 1547125307L), dominance = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), blocknum = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), trialnum = 1:20, 
 condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CFS", class = "factor"), 
 eyesidecfs = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("lefteye", 
 "righteye"), class = "factor"), stimside = structure(c(2L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("left", "right"), class = "factor"), 
 stimpos = c(-97L, -97L, -83L, -55L, -47L, -1L, 61L, 46L, 
 -4L, 28L, -60L, 16L, 11L, 77L, 96L, 52L, -29L, 23L, 84L, 
 93L), stimulus = structure(c(6L, 41L, 13L, 45L, 1L, 45L, 
 40L, 44L, 19L, 38L, 13L, 35L, 39L, 16L, 3L, 33L, 25L, 4L, 
 2L, 9L), .Label = c("attr_male_0.bmp", "attr_male_1.bmp", 
 "attr_male_10.bmp", "attr_male_11.bmp", "attr_male_12.bmp", 
 "attr_male_13.bmp", "attr_male_14.bmp", "attr_male_15.bmp", 
 "attr_male_16.bmp", "attr_male_17.bmp", "attr_male_18.bmp", 
 "attr_male_19.bmp", "attr_male_2.bmp", "attr_male_20.bmp", 
 "attr_male_21.bmp", "attr_male_3.bmp", "attr_male_4.bmp", 
 "attr_male_5.bmp", "attr_male_6.bmp", "attr_male_7.bmp", 
 "attr_male_8.bmp", "attr_male_9.bmp", "practice_0.png", "practice_1.png", 
 "unattr_male_0.bmp", "unattr_male_1.bmp", "unattr_male_10.bmp", 
 "unattr_male_11.bmp", "unattr_male_12.bmp", "unattr_male_13.bmp", 
 "unattr_male_14.bmp", "unattr_male_15.bmp", "unattr_male_16.bmp", 
 "unattr_male_17.bmp", "unattr_male_18.bmp", "unattr_male_19.bmp", 
 "unattr_male_2.bmp", "unattr_male_20.bmp", "unattr_male_21.bmp", 
 "unattr_male_3.bmp", "unattr_male_4.bmp", "unattr_male_5.bmp", 
 "unattr_male_6.bmp", "unattr_male_7.bmp", "unattr_male_8.bmp", 
 "unattr_male_9.bmp"), class = "factor"), response = structure(c(1L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("num_5", "s", "None"), class = "factor"), 
 correct = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), latency = c("0.957696499963", 
 "0.791598779233", "1.10196583883", "1.47500942541", "1.10195224516", 
 "0.874937406699", "0.974977383185", "0.891667885011", "0.925115802807", 
 "1.29170322855", "1.10850134231", "1.27520744911", "2.82531718331", 
 "1.40841043117", "2.24205221134", "1.1019921939", "0.74171666964", 
 "1.32521745017", "1.12505149643", "0.891592148851"), stimulus2 = structure(c(6L, 
 41L, 13L, 45L, 1L, 45L, 40L, 44L, 19L, 38L, 13L, 35L, 39L, 
 16L, 3L, 33L, 25L, 4L, 2L, 9L), .Label = c("attr_male_0.bmp", 
 "attr_male_1.bmp", "attr_male_10.bmp", "attr_male_11.bmp", 
 "attr_male_12.bmp", "attr_male_13.bmp", "attr_male_14.bmp", 
 "attr_male_15.bmp", "attr_male_16.bmp", "attr_male_17.bmp", 
 "attr_male_18.bmp", "attr_male_19.bmp", "attr_male_2.bmp", 
 "attr_male_20.bmp", "attr_male_21.bmp", "attr_male_3.bmp", 
 "attr_male_4.bmp", "attr_male_5.bmp", "attr_male_6.bmp", 
 "attr_male_7.bmp", "attr_male_8.bmp", "attr_male_9.bmp", 
 "practice_0.png", "practice_1.png", "unattr_male_0.bmp", 
 "unattr_male_1.bmp", "unattr_male_10.bmp", "unattr_male_11.bmp", 
 "unattr_male_12.bmp", "unattr_male_13.bmp", "unattr_male_14.bmp", 
 "unattr_male_15.bmp", "unattr_male_16.bmp", "unattr_male_17.bmp", 
 "unattr_male_18.bmp", "unattr_male_19.bmp", "unattr_male_2.bmp", 
 "unattr_male_20.bmp", "unattr_male_21.bmp", "unattr_male_3.bmp", 
 "unattr_male_4.bmp", "unattr_male_5.bmp", "unattr_male_6.bmp", 
 "unattr_male_7.bmp", "unattr_male_8.bmp", "unattr_male_9.bmp"
 ), class = "factor"), Group = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = 5:24, class = "data.frame")```
````

Comment: Look at `latency` in the `dput()`:  `latency = c("0.957696499963", ...`.  It's a character vector, not a numeric vector.

Comment: I can´t seem to turn it into a numeric vector.
as.numeric(df2$latency) just does nothing. Any Ideas?

Comment: with the small extract you provide above, when i do `df2$latency <- as.numeric(df2$latency)`, i do end up with a numeric field. is it possible that in your full dataframe, there are some weird non-numeric values in latency?

Comment: Max, just calling `as.numeric(df2$latency)` will not save the result.  You need to do what @user2474226 suggested.